# Use a 12 volt bulb in 110 AC socket?

Tags: voltage, adapter

If I were go get [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006LC2194) light bulb (with the following specs).  Would there be a way to use it in a standard U.S. light socket?

```
Specifications:
  Interface type: E27
  Input voltage: 12V
  Power: 3W
```

I am interested in even the weird solutions, though they may be of only intellectual benefit.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use an AC to DC adapter that you may already have.  Like the one you use to power your router and/or modem, just make sure it has 12 VDC output and can provide at least: $$ 3W/12V = 250 mA $$ which almost surely is the case, but you need to check it to make sure (the output voltage and current capacity should be on a sticker).

If the bulb doesn't turn on at the first try, flip the polarity and try again.

If you want to make it permanent you could get a light socket and wire it to the AC adaptor (instead of directly to mains).

Answer (score 1):

I just saw the link which you have for the bulb. I do not know about the US light socket, but it is very possible to use it with a 110V AC power supply. The crude way would be to have a transformer to step the voltage down and then rectify it to convert to DC (because the link I followed mentioned LED, which happen to use DC voltage). The sophisticated way would be to use a 12V DC output "adapter" and connect its output to the same bulb holder that can hold this bulb.

Comment: why you need to rectify ? The bulb itself work as a rectifier.

Comment: I do not think that the bulb has inbuilt rectifier because it is mentioned in the specification section that input voltage is 12V. As a rule of thumb, this voltage level inherently implies that it is DC unless explicitly mentioned otherwise. If there is rectifier (and transformer) inside, then you only need a bulb holder and the specification section should have familiar 110-220V words instead of 12V.

@Dave Thank you very much for brushing up my response

Answer (score 1):

Rewire the power source to a string of E27 sockets and buy enough to make it worth while.
Put  12DC on the string of E27 sockets and switch DC output using existing AC cable.  Insert the DC output hardwired from the breaker service panel exclusive for the E27 ceiling lights or outlets for E27 luminaires.

> This $11 supply is 48W @12V is one possible source to drive the DC
>   output. You can run sixteen (16) of these 3W Lights on this low cost
>   power source. Consider a ceiling full of potlights.

The advantage is the LEDs are much cheaper < $1/W and the power source is cheap ($0.25/W) making a lower cost solution to E27 LED lights with converters in each bulb for AC.  The 16 guage house wire will not cuase significant drop this source to destination in the house and regulation meets the load requirements.  Wiring it however may need an electrician to alter the wiring, but it is pretty easy.

Use Black wire ( normally = line ) for the + side for polarity convenience.

[image]
[**newegg link**](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0MX0942147)